# I am trying to send approximately 400 emails using Gmail.sendmail and get the message Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: email

Tags: gmail-api

I am only able to send 100 emails. the workspace allowance says I should be able to send 2000 emails or  500 emails for the trial period. How do I resolve this issue.
This is a problem for me as I need to be able too generate emails with a link and a unique code for the approximately 400 people.

Here is the script

```
function sendPDFForm()
{
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
  sendEmailWithAttachment(row);
}

function sendEmailWithAttachment(row)
{
 var filename= 'RCDocument.pdf';
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
  
  if (!file.hasNext()) 
  {
    console.error("Could not open file "+filename);
    return;
  }
  
  var client = getClientInfo(row);
  
  var template = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('email-template');
  template.client = client;
  var message = template.evaluate().getContent();

  



//  MailApp.sendEmail({
//    to: client.email,
//    subject: "Message from your Residents" +"' " + "Council",

  GmailApp.sendEmail(client.email,'Council election information','Please read the attached ',{attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)] ,
    name: 'Residents Council Election Information '});


}

function getClientInfo(row)
{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
   
   var values = sheet.getRange(row,1,row,4).getValues();
   var rec = values[0];
  
  var client = 
      {
        cname: rec[3],
        code:  rec[1],
        email: rec[0]
      };
  client.name = client.cname;
  return client;
}

function sendFormToAll()
{
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  
   var last_row = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  
   for(var row=1; row <= last_row; row++)
   {
     sendEmailWithAttachment(row);
     sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue("email sent");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Gmail caps it at a 100 emails for 3rd party applications. I think the greater allowance is only if you send it directly through the gmail app. Here is the link
https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en
Here is a screenshot [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zRGT.png)